# Get current Activity reference from within Service

Tags: android, service, android-activity

So say there's an app running (any app). I'd like to be able to get it's `Activity` from within a `Service` that will be triggered to run from a `android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. Other people's apps are not running in your process -- ergo, you cannot have access to any of that app's objects.

Comment: Is there anyway to activate a screen rotation from within a `Service` without having the `Activity`?

Comment: @mlevit: Ask the user to turn the device. :-) Beyond that, I am not aware of any options.